# java- javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am trying to execute my SQL statement as follows:

```
public String get_value(long nodeid,String ts) {
        try {
            String sql="Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL="+nodeid;
            em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
            if (em == null) {
                throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
            }
          //  return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();



        }
       return null;
    }
```

And it throws the exception message:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:could not execute statement
```

When I call executeUpdate().

Did I do anything wrong?

EDIT:
I am trying to pass the URL parameter in this format:

```
http://126.32.3.11:8080/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0=27491&ts=2019.03.20.16.50.58
```

And use these parameters to check if they exist in the column,if yes,then run my viewPDF.jsp

```
 public String get_value(long nodeid,String ts) {
        try {
            String sql="Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL="+"'f0='"+nodeid+"'&ts='"+ts;
            em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
            if (em == null) {
                throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
            }
          //  return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();



        }
       return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`executeUpdate()` is for update and delete query.

For select query use `getResultList()` or `getSingleResult()` to retrieve results

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
List<Object[]> result= q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I'm basically trying to check if an exact record exist in one of my column,if yes then execute the page JSP.

Comment: Read answer and try to understand what it is saying

Comment: I still got SQLGrammarException